# Getting intellisense to work for objects in jquery each() callback

Tags: jquery, intellisense

In VS2015 (also I believe in 2013), how do I get intellisense to recognise objects inside a jquery callback? In the code below (the 'test' function), inside the non-jquery loop intellisense knows what a 'person' is, but the $.each() callback doesn't.

```
var Person = (function () {
    "use strict";
    var person = function (name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    };
    return person;
}());
var People = (function () {
    "use strict";
    var people = function (lang) {
        this.language = lang;
        this.population = [];
    };
    return people;
}());
var test = (function () {
    "use strict";
    var i, person, people = new People('English');
    people.population.push(new Person('joe', 30));
    people.population.push(new Person('jane', 31));

    // method1 : intellisense works - knows what a 'person' is.
    for (i = 0; i < people.population.length; i++) {
        person = people.population[i];
        person.age++;
    }
    // method2 : intellisense does not work
    $.each(people.population, function (index, person) {
        person.age++;
    });
    person = people.population[0];
    alert(person.name + "'s age is now" + person.age);
 }());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the javascript array.forEach() method, instead of jquery each(), does allow intellisense to understand the array elements.

```
people.population.forEach(function (person) {
    person.age += 1;
});
```

But it seems that both these methods are much slower than the basic 'for' loop, so for big arrays I'll stick with that.